# Given $|f(x) - f(y)| \le \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$ what are the points of intersection of the graph of $y = f(x)$ and the line $y = x$?

Tags: functions, contest-math

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued function, defined for all real numbers $x$ such that $$|f(x) - f(y)| \le \frac{1}{2}|x-y|$$
for all $x,y$.

Then the number of points of intersection of the graph of $y = f(x)$ and the line $y = x$ is?

What does such a condition on $f$ imply? I realize it implies continuity, but that doesn't help me solve the question. How should I do so?

Comment: That is a direct application of Banach fixed point theorem. Then it follows that $f$ has exactly one fixed point, that is, one intersection of the graph of $f$ with the line $y=x$.

Comment: @Nameless: You can't use the Mean Value Theorem unless your function is differentiable, which is not necessarily the case here.

Comment: @TonyK, I jumped ahead of myself here. You are definitely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very strong condition on the continuity of $f$, implying that $f$ is [Lipschitz continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity), which implies that $f'$ exists almost everywhere and is essentially bounded by $1/2$. Morally, it means that around any point on the graph of $f$, if we draw lines with slope $\pm 1/2$ through that point, the graph of $f$ lies between them. So $f$ cannot grow quickly at all.

---

Now to find the number of intersections: First, convince yourself that an intersection must exist, after studying carefully the continuity of $f$. Once you've done this, note that if $x$ and $y$ are both fixed points of $f$, then

$$|x - y| = |f(x) - f(y)| \le \frac 1 2 |x - y|$$

But what nonnegative number is bounded by half of itself?

Comment: Yes I understand. But why must an intersection exist?

And well so does that imply that there is one fixed point?

Comment: Yes, there is a unique intersection point. Geometrically, $f$ is almost like a line with slope $1/2$, and this picture should guide you in finding a proof that an intersection point exists.

Comment: Ahh I understand. Thanks.
Since $f$ is "like" a line with slope $1/2 \neq 1$ there must be an at least one intersection.